# Check if macro param is defined in optional capture (Declarative Macro Syntax)

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I am creating a fairly complex macro and can't use the overloading syntax to create my macros.  I am trying to conditionally check if a prop has been defined within an optional capture group or not:

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    (name: $name: ident$(, media: $media: tt)?) => {
        pub struct $name;
        impl $name {
            // how do i use media here and also provide default
            // const MEDIA: &str = IF_DEFINED $media { $media } ELSE { "DEFAULT" };
        }
    };
}

foo! {
    name: Hey,
    media: "hey"
}

foo! {
    name: Hey2
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=be34630348a955d27786b0010d36574c)

Comment: *"can't use the overloading syntax"* - why not? It seems like a natural choice to me

Comment: @kmdreko because my param syntax is using the optional thing in a repeat group so I can't overload it

Comment: Why do you make `$media` in macro repeated? Referring to `const MEDIA: &str` I consider only one is needed.

Comment: @rustyhu because my macro is more complex than the example and uses a lot of other code in my crate so I listed the constraints out and then gave a minimal reproduction

Comment: @sno2 Could you post a more realistic example that shows why you assume you can't use the overloading syntax? Maybe there's a catch allowing that you actually could use it.

Comment: You can always use recursion and use overload syntax in the inner recursion levels: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d82161a7ab896c09ca1cbc50ac8ecaae)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the constraints you mentioned, you can achieve conditional checking by the following workaround:

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    (name: $name: ident$(, media: $media: tt)?) => {
        
            pub struct $name;
     
            impl $name {
                const MEDIA: &'static str = [$($media ,)? "DEFAULT"][0];
            }
    };
}

foo! {
    name: Hey,
    media: "hey"
}

foo! {
    name: Hey2
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", Hey::MEDIA);
    println!("{}", Hey2::MEDIA);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e5a71c12ec1e5e3b3b04bab8b6cd9552)